# One liner echo using $(...)

Tags: bash

I can get the following to work:

```
self=$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
echo "Sourcing $self"
```

But not the following (I want a one liner):

```
echo "Sourcing $(readlink -f \"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}\")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution starts a new quoting context, so the quotes in the `readlink` command are not nested in the quotes surrounding the argument to `echo`. You don't need to escape them.

```
echo "Sourcing $(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
echo 'Sourcing' $(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
```